# Is there a java library which could extract the first seen date and the last seen date of an address over a bitcoin network?

Tags: address, java, library

Apparently the bitcoinj does not provide such feature.

Comment: Not sure what bitcoinj offers, but can't you get all transactions that involve an address? If you got such a list, you could just look at the dates of the first and the last transaction in the list to get the information you want. Is that what you mean by "seen date"?

Comment: I don't think you can. https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14.4/ The Address class does not have a method for getting all transactoins.